# Arduino Automatic Light Dimmer

Tags: java, arduino, light, neopixel

I am trying to make an NEOPIXEL by Adafruit to be dimmed down by only entering the number of seconds but I can't achieve a smooth transition and it only work with up to 5 seconds. And I can't get it to print the current brightness. :(

Here is my code:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define PIN 4

// Parameter 1 = number of pixels in strip
// Parameter 2 = pin number (most are valid)
// Parameter 3 = pixel type flags, add together as needed:
//   NEO_KHZ800  800 KHz bitstream (most NeoPixel products w/WS2812 LEDs)
//   NEO_KHZ400  400 KHz (classic 'v1' (not v2) FLORA pixels, WS2811 drivers)
//   NEO_GRB     Pixels are wired for GRB bitstream (most NeoPixel products)
//   NEO_RGB     Pixels are wired for RGB bitstream (v1 FLORA pixels, not     v2)
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(3, PIN, NEO_GRB +         NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {

  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'

}

void loop() {
  double t = 2000;
  dimmerByTime(t);

}
void dimmerByTime(int time){
int seq = time / 170;
int b = 100 /seq;
  for (int i = 1; i < seq; i++) {
  strip.setPixelColor(0, 0, 100, 200);
  strip.setPixelColor(1, 0, 100, 10);
  strip.setPixelColor(2, 0, 0, 225);
  strip.setBrightness(b);
  strip.show();
  delay(170);
  b = b + b;
  Serial.println(i);
  Serial.println("Brightness @");
  Serial.println(b);
  }
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: `#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>` - that's **not** *Java*. Please tag your question correctly.

Comment: `b = b + b;` is the same as `b = b * 2;` or `b *= 2;`.

Answer (score 0):

To enable printing, in void setup() add: Serial.begin(9600);

Double t = 2000; can be int t = 2000;

In function dimmerByTime, the for loop only loops 10 times (seq = 2000/170 = 11).
int b doubles every time (first: b=9, second: b=18 etc.).
Try a fixed number and see whats happening (e.g. b += 10).
Or try an even smaller step and remove (or reduce) the delay, in conjuction with the for-loop (iterate more then 10).

Dimming is often playing with different variable settings.